# Sum multiple values from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to identify the cost of an engine depending which parts it will use.

I have one sheet that has the cost of each part for each engine model. There are 3 engine models and nearly 500 parts (!Parts).

In another sheet I try to sum the value of all the various combinations of parts. (!EngineCost). I use a "1" to indicate the inclusion of that part. I grab the prices from !Parts and total them per engine size.

At the moment I am doing this very manually (see below). Is there a better way to do this?

=IF(O3=1,'Parts'!$R$6,"0")+IF(P3=1,'Parts'!$R$7,"0")+IF(Q3=1,'Parts'!$R$8,"0")

Thanks!

Here is link to a sample sheet https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbh5muf7721mk0s/engine.xlsx

Comment: your formula could be simplified as follows: `=MMULT(O3:Q3,'Parts'!R6:R8)`. Is it what you need? If not - it would be great to show the stucture of your sheets

Comment: @simoco that is not the same thing. If the cells in `O3:Q3` have any value other than `1`, you will multiply by that number. Your formula assumes that if they are not 1, they must be zero. It may well be true but it's not quite how the question is written.

Comment: @Floris, maybe you are right, `I use a "1" to indicate the inclusion of that part` - I assumed that `1` indicates inclusion and otherwise - `0` or empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first hunch was that you could use the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(O3:O6, 1, 'Parts'!$R$6:$R$8)
```

This sum the values in `'Parts'!$R$6:$R$8` when the corresponding cell in `O3:O6` is equal to 1.

However, as @simoco pointed out, you have a transpose - one array is transposed relative to the other. That make this very slightly more challenging. You need two steps:

1. find the cells that have a value of 1
2. sum those cells

The following can do it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((O3:Q3=1), TRANSPOSE('Parts'!$R$6:$R$8))
```

entered as an array formula*); or, taking advantage of the fact that matrix multiplication is really the element by element multiplication of a row vector with a column vector, followed by taking the sum:

```
=MMULT(I3:K3,IF(G4:G6=1,1,0))
```

again entered as an array formula*).

**) Array formula is entered by pressing ctrl-shift-enter on PC, or cmd-shift-enter on Mac.*

Comment: Floris, as I see, it should be sumif but not sumifs, however both not work, since one range is horizontal and another - vertical. It should be something like this: `=SUMPRODUCT((O3:Q3=1)*TRANSPOSE('Parts'!$R$6:$R$8))` with array entry

Comment: @simoco you are right, I didn't spot that one was transposed. I have updated with a couple of alternatives, with a thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks Guys! This worked - =SUMPRODUCT((O3:Q3=1), TRANSPOSE('Parts'!$R$6:$R$8))